# The promise resolves but the code doesn't proceed

Tags: javascript

I have a wired issue with my function. you don't need to read and understand every part of the function although I've copied all the functions for you to have a look. The `MovieAudio` function has `PlayAudio()` function inside and it's where the issue exist ...

We have this line of code inside `PlayAudio()` function:

```
console.log('before sfx');
if(sfx) { await sfxPlay(sfx.before_listen); } 
console.log('after sfx');
```

As you see we have two console logs right before and after this line. If `sfxPlay` promise resolves we should see the `console.log('after sfx');` but we never see this unfortunately!

I have tested the `await sfxPlay(sfx.before_listen);` another place outside of this code and it works correctly!

In the first sight I thought maybe `sfxPlay` function doesn't resolve correctly so I put `console.log('sfx has been resolved');` inside `sfxPlay` function to check if `sfxPlay` function is resolved correctly, and yes it resolves correctly but still we don't proceed to  `console.log('after sfx')`

Here is my console. note that we don't see `console.log('after sfx')` which we except to see of course:

[image]

What am I missing? it seems simple but it doesn't behave correctly?

```
let StopMovieAudio;

function MovieAudio(duration, stress, option = {}) {

    let movieAudioResolve;
    const speed = option.speed ? option.speed : 1;
    const sfx = option.sfx ? false : true;
    const guideIndex =  option.guideIndex ? [...Array(option.guideIndex).keys()] : []; 
    if(!stress) stress = { to: '__', from: '__', within: ['__-__'] };
    const guide = !!guideIndex.length;
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    document.body.appendChild(video);
    video.id = 'audio-clip'; 
    const clip = document.getElementById("audio-clip");
    clip.style.visibility = "hidden";
    const source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = getBlob(clipSource);
    source.type = 'video/mp4';
    video.appendChild(source);
    video.load();
    const start = duration.start + startPlus;
    const end = duration.end + endPlus;

    PlayAudio();
    
    async function PlayAudio() {
        clip.currentTime = start;
        clip.playbackRate = speed;
        console.log('sfx', sfx);
        console.log('before sfx');
        if(sfx) { await sfxPlay(sfx.before_listen); } // sfx is true and we enter the if block
        console.log('after sfx');
        StartAudio();
        const endCheck = setInterval(endCheckInterval, 5);
        function endCheckInterval() {
            guidePhraseUpper(guideIndex[0]);
            checkStopMovie();
        }
    } // end of Play function

    function checkStopMovie() {
        if (clip.currentTime >= end) {
            clearInterval(endCheck);
            StopMovieAudio();
            guidePhrasesDown();
        }
    }

    function guidePhraseUpper(index) {
        if(!guideIndex.length) return;
        if (clip.currentTime >= portionDurations[index].start) {
            guideIndex.shift();
            guidePhrasesDown();
            guidePhraseUp(movieSentenceArrayEn[index]);
        }
    }

    function guidePhrasesDown() {
        if(!guide) return;
        const component = $(`iframe[src*='${components.chief}']`)[0];
        referenceString.split(' ').forEach((phrase, index) => component.contentWindow.guideWordDown(index));
    }

    function StartAudio() {
        console.log('start of StartAudio');
        clip.volume = 1;
        clip.play();
        stressEffectTo();
        stressEffectFrom();
        stressEffectWithin();
    } 

    StopMovieAudio = () => {
        const audioClip = document.getElementById("audio-clip");
        if(audioClip) { document.body.removeChild(audioClip); }
        if(typeof StopMovieAudio === "function") { movieAudioResolve(); }
    } 

    function stressEffectTo() {
        if(stress.to.includes('_')) { return; }
        clip.playbackRate = 0.75;
        speedUpFrom(stress.to);
    }

    function stressEffectFrom() {
        if(stress.from.includes('_')) { return; }
        clip.playbackRate = 1;
        speedDownFrom(stress.from);
    }

    function stressEffectWithin() {
        const stressWithin = stress.within.filter(w => !w.includes('_'));
        if(!stressWithin.length){ return; }
        for(let i = 0; i < stressWithin.length; i++) {
            speedDownFrom(stressWithin[i].split('-')[0]);
            speedUpFrom(stressWithin[i].split('-')[1]);
        }
    } // end of stressEffectWithin function

    function speedUpFrom(timer) {
        const endCheck = setInterval(endCheckInterval, 5);
        function endCheckInterval() {
            if (clip.currentTime >= timer) {
                clearInterval(endCheck);
                clip.playbackRate = 1;
            }
        }
    } // end of Track function

    function speedDownFrom(timer) {
        const endCheck = setInterval(endCheckInterval, 5);
        function endCheckInterval() {
            if (clip.currentTime >= timer) {
                clearInterval(endCheck);
                clip.playbackRate = 0.7;
            }
        }
    } // end of Track function

    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        movieAudioResolve = resolve;
        console.log('Promise reached');
    });

} // end of MovieAudio function

let sfxPlayResolve;

function sfxPlay(source) {
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        sfxPlayResolve = resolve;
        const sfxAudio = new Audio(source);
        playingAudios.push(sfxAudio);
        sfxAudio.play();
        sfxAudio.onerror = function() {
            console.log("Error loading: " + this.src);
            sfxPlay(sfx.no_sources);
            resolve(); 
        }
        sfxAudio.addEventListener("ended", function() {  
            sfxAudio.currentTime = 0;          
            resolve();    
            console.log('sfx has been resolved');    
        }); 
    });
}
```

### Update

A Codepen has been added (I have commented the if block (where the issue exist) to show you the correct behavior of the function and You need to click on somewhere to play the audio of the video):

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/mdOVgZw

Comment: Put the whole `sfxPlay` function content inside a `try` block starting with `const sfxAudio = new Audio(source);...` and see if an error is thrown before it can reach those `resolve()` statements.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it for you to have deep look and try...

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/mdOVgZw

Comment: You need to click on somewhere in 5 seconds to play the audio of the video...

Comment: I have commented the if block (where the issue exist) to show you the correct behavior of the function

Comment: It works in codepen... What a confusion :((((((

Comment: Yep, it indeed does work.

Comment: So why it doesn't work in my code?

Comment: I guess I found out the issue I'm going to try once more and come back to you... :)

Comment: It was obvious in the code but we missed it...

Answer (score 1):

try calling the play function like this:

```
let flag = true;
    sfxAudio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {  
        console.log('sfx can play');
        flag && this.play();
        flag = false;
    });
```

I think it is a race condition, that would also explain why your code fails locally, but works in the codepen.

The docs also recommend an Event-based approach to calling play():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio

Answer (score 0):

The user has to interact with the document, one cannot just autoplay a video. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

For me it works just fine when the `PlayAudio` function is run on clicking a button, like:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="startTheShow()">Play</button>
```

JS:

```
// setTimeout(async () => {
//   await MovieAudio({start: '3', end: '15'}, { to: '__', from: '__', within: ['__-__'] }, 1, true); 
// }, 5000);

const startTheShow = async () => {
  await MovieAudio({start: '3', end: '15'}, { to: '__', from: '__', within: ['__-__'] }, 1, true); 
}
```